# How to rotate the globe to specific country on orthographic highcharts maps built in projection

Tags: highcharts, map-projections

here is my current code:
https://codepen.io/tochkitx_renderspace/pen/MWqeMNO

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div class="globe-container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div id="globe"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.globe-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 913px;
  height: 506px;
}

.circle {
  width: 873px;
  height: 873px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    118.16deg,
    #be84cf 6.43%,
    #56c0f5 61.63%,
    #52fbff 100%
  );
  opacity: 0.2;
  z-index: 0;
}

#globe {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 750px;
  width: 750px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

The data is in codepen. Here's the rest of the code:

```
function initializeGlobe() {
  const self = this;
  const getGraticule = () => {
    const data = [];

    // Meridians
    for (let x = -180; x <= 180; x += 15) {
      data.push({
        geometry: {
          type: "LineString",
          coordinates:
            x % 90 === 0
              ? [
                  [x, -90],
                  [x, 0],
                  [x, 90]
                ]
              : [
                  [x, -80],
                  [x, 80]
                ]
        }
      });
    }

    // Latitudes
    for (let y = -90; y <= 90; y += 10) {
      const coordinates = [];
      for (let x = -180; x <= 180; x += 5) {
        coordinates.push([x, y]);
      }
      data.push({
        geometry: {
          type: "LineString",
          coordinates
        },
        lineWidth: y === 0 ? 2 : undefined
      });
    }

    return data;
  };

  this.chart = Highcharts.mapChart("globe", {
    chart: {
      map: topology,
      backgroundColor: "#dbf4fe",
      margin: 0,
      padding: 0,
      spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    },
    accessibility: {
      enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },

    title: {
      text: null
    },

    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },

    mapNavigation: {
      enabled: true,
      enableDoubleClickZoomTo: false
    },

    mapView: {
      maxZoom: 4,
      projection: {
        name: "Orthographic",
        rotation: [50, -20]
      },
      animation: true,
      zoom: 3
    },

    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },

    series: [
      {
        name: "Graticule",
        id: "graticule",
        type: "mapline",
        data: getGraticule(),
        enableMouseTracking: false
      },
      {
        data: countries,
        joinBy: "name",
        name: "",
        color: "#549ee2",
        borderColor: "#75aee1",
        cursor: "pointer",
        events: {
          click: (event) => {
            event.srcElement.point.select();
            event.srcElement.point.zoomTo();
          }
        },

        states: {
          normal: {
            animation: false
          },
          inactive: {
            color: "#75aee1",
            borderColor: "#75aee1",
            animation: {
              duration: 200
            }
          },
          select: {
            color: "#131660",
            borderColor: "#75aee1",
            enabled: true
          },
          hover: {
            color: "#131660",
            borderColor: "#75aee1",
            animation: {
              duration: 200
            }
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  const renderSea = () => {
    let verb = "animate";
    if (!this.chart.sea) {
      this.chart.sea = this.chart.renderer
        .circle()
        .attr({
          fill: {
            radialGradient: {
              cx: 0.4,
              cy: 0.4,
              r: 1
            },
            stops: [[0, "#dbf4fe"]]
          },
          zIndex: 0
        })
        .add(this.chart.get("graticule").group);
      verb = "attr";
    }

    const bounds = this.chart.get("graticule").bounds,
      p1 = this.chart.mapView.projectedUnitsToPixels({
        x: bounds.x1,
        y: bounds.y1
      }),
      p2 = this.chart.mapView.projectedUnitsToPixels({
        x: bounds.x2,
        y: bounds.y2
      });
    this.chart.sea[verb]({
      cx: (p1.x + p2.x) / 2,
      cy: (p1.y + p2.y) / 2,
      r: Math.min(p2.x - p1.x, p1.y - p2.y) / 2
    });
  };

  renderSea();
  Highcharts.addEvent(this.chart, "redraw", renderSea);
  this.rotateGlobe(this.chart);
}

function rotateGlobe(chart) {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const rotation = chart.mapView.projection.options.rotation;
    rotation[0] += 5;
    if (rotation[0] === 355) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    chart.update(
      {
        mapView: {
          projection: {
            rotation
          }
        }
      },
      void 0,
      void 0,
      false
    );
  }, 1);

  setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }, 10000);
}

initializeGlobe();
```

Questions:

1. how can I rotate the globe when I click on a single country so that selected country is centered on the screen?
2. Is there a simpler solution for the map data? Do I have to use the topojson or there is a way to use https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps for custom maps.
3. If I want to select an area (consist of multiple countries) is there a way to do that with current data or I have to load new data, and if I have to load new data how to do that?
4. The globe is jumping when zoomed in and when you start to pan again. I saw this solution https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hqzu9sLo/ but it's still buggy. Any solution for that?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `click` point event and update rotation for map view projection according to the clicked point coordinates.

   ```
   point: {
     events: {
       click: function() {
         const { latitude, longitude } = this;

         chart.update({
           mapView: {
             projection: {
               rotation: [-longitude, -latitude]
             }
           }
         });
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. You can use any of the supported map data. Please check the docs for maps: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started
3. You need to only enable: `allowPointSelect` option in series config.
4. It's a bug in Highcharts Maps, you can follow this GitHub issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18542

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jcyuwd50/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.point.events.click

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.allowPointSelect